# How to prepend function before calling by line a command by Artisan?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a doubt, I know that to call only laravel commands I have to use the command `Artisan::call('command name')` but how can I do it if I want to execute the following task

```
Artisan::call('cat archive | php artisan project:method'); //NOT WORK
cat name_file | php artisan project:method
```

For example I want to execute the command

```
CAT /tmp/archive.eml | php artisan command:name_method
```

Since what I want to do is to read files with cat that are in another directory through a foreach and enter the command that manipulates the data of those files.

Comment: `Artisan::call` ONLY calls commnds registed on your Laravel application, it is not used to run OS commands

Comment: And there is not a way to read external command to artisan? since I need to automate read 74.000 mails of log and it is something like this the command ```CAT /tmp/archive.eml | php artisan command:project```

Comment: You should have `Symfony Process` object available in Laravel, read this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html), you can execute anything there and read the output. If you don't have it, just composer require it as the docs says and play with it, if you can't still have something, I would say to either update the question or delete this one and create a new one related to `Process`